# How to compute $\tilde a (t)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Tapp's book on differential geometry and am trying to understand the following: How are they computing $\tilde a^{\perp}$ here?

> [image]

I've seen this previously in the book:

> [image]

From here, I know I might have to compute $\tilde a (t)= \tilde a (t)^{||}+\tilde a (t)^{\perp}$ and I know $\tilde a (t)$.

> [image]

But here, I am extremely confused at how to compute $a^{||}$. Can you help?

Comment: A citation is needed for the source of these images.  Presumably "the book" is a text on differential geometry, but relying primarily on three images to set up your Question gives the Reader a feeling of walking into the middle of a story.

Comment: @hardmath Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, by definition, $\mathbf x^\perp = \mathbf x - \mathbf x^\parallel$ for any vector $\mathbf x$. Thus, because projection is linear (which you should be familiar with, since Linear Algebra is listed as a prerequisite to understanding the text, but which should also be straightforward to show from the formula), you don't need to actually calculate $\mathbf a^\parallel$ to calculate $\tilde{\mathbf a}^\perp$ in terms of $\mathbf a^\perp$, but rather $\mathbf v^\perp$. To see this, observe that for all $t$,
\begin{align}
    \tilde{\mathbf a}^\perp(t) &= \phi''(t) \mathbf v(\phi(t)) + \phi'(t)^2 \mathbf a(t) - \left(\phi''(t) \mathbf v(\phi(t)) + \phi'(t)^2 \mathbf a(t)\right)^\parallel\\
                               &= \phi''(t) \mathbf v(\phi(t)) + \phi'(t)^2 \mathbf a(t) - \phi''(t) \mathbf v^\parallel(\phi(t)) - \phi'(t)^2 \mathbf a^\parallel(t)\\
                               &= \phi''(t) \left(\mathbf v(\phi(t)) - \mathbf v^\parallel(\phi(t))\right) + \phi'(t)^2 \left(\mathbf a(t) - \mathbf a^\parallel(t)\right)\\
                               &= \phi''(t) \mathbf v^\perp(\phi(t)) + \phi'(t)^2 \mathbf a^\perp(t).
\end{align}
(We've essentially just shown that $\cdot^\perp$ is also linear, which the author seems to view as trivial). To complete the proof, we just need to note that for all $t$, because $\mathbf v(\phi(t))$ is parallel to $\tilde{\mathbf v}(t)$, $\mathbf 0$ is orthogonal to $\tilde{\mathbf v}(t)$, and $\mathbf v(\phi(t)) = \mathbf v(\phi(t)) + \mathbf0$, Proposition and Definition 1.13 tells us that $\mathbf v^\perp(\phi(t)) = \mathbf0$.

Comment: I am still a bit confused as to the second vector. I think I should use the formula given there: 

$$x^{||}=\langle x,y_1\rangle y_1 + \langle x,y_2\rangle y_2$$

I think the basis is given by $\tilde a, \tilde v$ so we have:

$$\tilde a^{||}=\langle \tilde a,\tilde a\rangle \tilde a + \langle \tilde a,\tilde v\rangle \tilde v$$

From here, I think we have:

$$\tilde a^{||}=|\tilde a|^2 \tilde a+\langle \phi(t)v(\phi(t)), \phi''(t)v(\phi(t))+ \phi'(t)^2a(\phi(t))\rangle \tilde v $$

Comment: Which I think yields:

$$\tilde a^{||}=|\tilde a|^2 \tilde a+ (\langle \phi(t)v(\phi(t)), \phi''(t)v(\phi(t)) \rangle +\langle \phi(t)v(\phi(t)) ,\phi'(t)^2a(\phi(t)) \rangle)v$$

$$\tilde a^{||}=|\tilde a|^2 \tilde a+ (\phi(t) \phi''(t) |v(\phi(t)|^2 +\phi(t)\phi'(t)^2 \langle v(\phi(t)),a(\phi(t)) \rangle)v$$

Comment: I suspect you and the book author are using something much simpler I couldn't discover yet.

Comment: @RedBanana You're only doing the projection onto the span of a single vector, $\tilde{\mathbf v}$. Also, note that the projection formula you're using is only for an *orthonormal* set of vectors, and there's no guarantee that $\tilde{\mathbf v}$ is unit-length.

Comment: I tried to do the projection over $\tilde v$ but the formula got big and I didn't achieve the same result. I'll try again later to see what comes up.

Comment: @RedBanana I've edited the answer to hopefully address some of your other concerns.

Comment: Thanks. I read it and understood most of it but there is something unclear to me: Why $\mathbf v(\phi(t))$ being parallel to $\tilde{\mathbf v}(t)$ implies $\mathbf v^\perp(\phi(t)) = \mathbf0$?

Comment: Because of the uniqueness claim in Proposition and Definition 1.13